# Jquery input manipulation not working at all

Tags: jquery, html, web

I feel like this shouldn't be happening since it's such an easy thing to do, but still :

I can't seem to be able to manipulate input fields... See this jsfiddle of what i've tried so far and is not working : http://jsfiddle.net/53mMY/2/

Basically, all i want to do is to modify the text's input when the user's mouse click on it (or on mouse enter, perhaps)

Even though i used selectors like `#username` or `input[name="username"]`, both the event and the val setter aren't working.

I've read the jquery doc and they mention nothing about this...

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE (seems to work fine in jsfiddle but not in my project):**

Stripped down code :

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/desktop.css" />   

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anaheim' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php require_once "login_header.php"; ?>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <?php require_once "footer.php"; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

login_header.php :

```
<div>
    <script>
        $('#username').val("yup");
        console.log("nownow....");
        $('input[name="username"]').click(function(){
            console.log("hello!");
        });
    </script>
    <h2> <?php echo lang("login_header.title");?> </h2>
    <form>
        <label for="username"><?php echo lang("login_header.username");?> :</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username">
        <label for="password"><?php echo lang("login_header.password");?> :</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to link jQuery in the fiddle

Comment: my bad, in my document it is linked, i'll modify it right away.

Comment: thats weird... apparently it's working fine when it's on jsfiddle :/.

Comment: It's about time to post real code, isn't it?

Comment: @Andrei True enough, i posted it.

Comment: And now the problem is clear. See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your jsFiddle puts everything in the `onLoad` handler, on the actual page script is run immediately before the html controls are rendered. Simply wrap it in the callback:

```
$(function() {
    $('#username').val("yup");
    console.log("nownow....");
    $('input[name="username"]').click(function(){
        console.log("hello!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Well that was the problem! Thanks. Just as a side question though, why do i need to put my code in a "document.ready" when it is an event? (click, for example)

Comment: because otherwise jquery tries to add the eventlistener on not existing elements wich means that the acutall elements gets added afterwards with no eventlistner tied to them!

Comment: @zaedas99, sure. The problem here is that this code is executed immediately, that is jQuery tries to find the elements you are refering to in the document and in first case set a value for it, in the second case bind an event handler to it. Obviously this is impossible since there are no elements yet on the page. For the deffered assignment of event handlers you can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), however, if not intentional, it is alwasy a good idea to wait until whole page is loaded before executing scripts

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put your script inside document ready handler-

```
$(function(){
    $('#username').val("yup");
    console.log("nownow....");
    $('input[name="username"]').click(function(){
        console.log("hello!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to manipulate input field you do like this

Html

```
<input id=text type=text value=foo>
```

Jquery

```
$("#text").click(function(){
    $(this).val("bar");
});
```

**Edit:** 
You can see this in my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/53mMY/5/

Why your jquery isn't working in your fiddle could probably be because you hadn't toldjsfiddle to include jquery sourcefile

Comment: Right, that's what i'm doing... And on top of it my example is working on jsfiddle. Please see the update of my question